# How do I mock static function (Object function, not class function) in scala

Tags: scala, object, easymock

```
Object A {
  def a = { something}
}
```

---

```
// I've import A, but still have error message:  not found: type A
val x = mock[A]
```

Comment: (`object`, not `Object`? applicable updates left to poster)

Comment: The type of `object A` is `A.type`. If you want to define type `A`, you need to e.g. define `class A { /* as now */ }` and then `object A extends A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find [this email thread](http://groups.google.com/group/scala-melb/browse_thread/thread/63bfa588bca1cd0d#) instructive.

Whilst pure mocking of the object is not possible with any tool yet, the thread above does have a few options for you. All of which involve changing your design to some degree.

Answer (score 7):

You don't. Not only `A` is not a type or class -- it is an instance -- but it is an instance of a singleton (`A.type`).

What you do instead is put your methods on a `trait`, and make the object extend it. Then, you mock the trait instead of mocking the object.