# Mock Java static class from scala

Tags: java, scala, java-8, mockito, scalatest

Any idea how from ScalaTest I can mock a static Java class??

I have this code

```
  val mockMapperComponent: IMapperComponent = mock[IMapperComponent]
  val applicationContext: ApplicationContext = mock[ApplicationContext]

  val appContextUtil: AppContextUtil = mock[AppContextUtil]


  override def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    mockStatic(classOf[AppContextUtil])
    when(AppContextUtil.getApplicationContext).thenReturn(applicationContext)
    when(applicationContext.getBean(classOf[IMapperComponent])).thenReturn(mockMapperComponent)

  }
```

In Java `mockStatic` with the annotation in the class `@PrepareForTest({AppContextUtil.class})` do the trick, but from Scala I can only found in scalaTest documentation how to mock the normal access, but not static.

Regards.

Comment: Have you looked at [How do I mock static function (Object function, not class function) in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696815/how-do-i-mock-static-function-object-function-not-class-function-in-scala)?

Comment: I’m afraid not yet. Seems like it’s not a very extended topic. At least not in mockito power mock

Answer (score 3):

Mocking Java static method in Scala is more involved than in Java because Mockito API use Java's ability to implicit cast a single-function
interface to pointer of a function, for example:
`httpClientStaticMock.when(HttpClientBuilder::build).thenReturn(httpClientBuilder);` notice function pointer usage:
`HttpClientBuilder::build`.

As scala compiler does not have the same implicit casting rules, we have to de-sugar this call explicitly:

```scala
val httpClientStaticMock = mockStatic(classOf[org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder])
try {
  httpClientStaticMock.when(new org.mockito.MockedStatic.Verification {
    override def apply(): Unit = org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.create()
  }).thenReturn(httpClientBuilder)

} finally {
  httpClientStaticMock.close()
}
```

Notice anonymous object usage to implement `Verification` interface: `new org.mockito.MockedStatic.Verification`.

Also, pay attention and do NOT forget to `close` static mocks in `finally` clause, otherwise very hard to troubleshoot
errors will happen.

Comment: Can you explain what the  block:
```new org.mockito.MockedStatic.Verification```  does? I'm trying to mock ```LocalDateTime.now``` and I don't get what I'm sopose to do inside the block

Comment: @MiguelSalas It calls a static function to be verified. In your case, it would be `LocalDateTime.now` and then in `thenReturn` you should provide mocking value.